# Post list to database with php

Tags: php, database, list, post

I have list:

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
</ul>
```

Usually php use form to input the data to server, but I want to post/send the list to database. What should I do?

Comment: You want to store list in database?

Comment: That's not a list, that's HTML. Please provide more background to your problem to help others to a better understanding.

Comment: Deadlock : Yes, actually the list is dynamic list not basic list...

Comment: Jack : Yeah sory, I mean HTML list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can have a hidden input on list, then on jquery you can have something like this when the button is clicked.

```
<li><input type="hidden" value="test" id="test">TEST</li>

<div id="content">
  <div id="sub_cont"><!--leave blank this is for the contents of postpage.php after button submit--></div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#button').click(function() {
       $('#sub_cont').fadeIn('fast');
       $("#content #sub_cont").load("postpage.php?id="+ $("#test").val());
     });
 });
</script>
```

on postpage.php

```
$test = $_REQUEST['id'];
<div id="content">
   <!--contents/result/etc/display test-->
</div>
```

sorry for lazy coding. you can experiment on other events.

Answer (score 0):

Get the values in the list using Jquery  and store in js variable.
Send an ajax request by including that js variable(list values) as a parameters and insert into db
or save this value in a hidden fields in and submit that form

Answer (score 0):

Well I would turn the list items into a variable. From there I would do something like this.
This is if you are using mysql. Hope this helps.

```
$one = "one";
$two = "two";

$SQLstring = "INSERT INTO tableName " .
    "(columnOne,columnTwo)" .
    "VALUES('$one', '$two')";

$QueryResult = @mysql_query($SQLstring, $DataBaseConnection);
```

Hope this helped.